# PHP PDO: Insert working without attributes

Tags: mysql

This question is about why something **is** working.

Using unnamed placeholders in PHP PDO:

```
$STH  = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO Person (firstname, lastname, age) values ("?, ?, ?")");
$STH->execute($the_data);
```

This sort of insertion works correctly.

However, it still works if written as

```
$STH  = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO Person () values ("?, ?, ?")");
$STH->execute($the_data);
```

Huh?
Are attribute names just syntactic sugar or something?

Comment: what cols do you have in your table? just those 3 or more than that?

Comment: Yes, just those three, and in that order (the latter of which, at least, is necessary when using unnamed placeholders iirc)

Comment: Either and both the column and value list may be empty. The predefined column order, and/or default values are used. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: @mario that seems to be the right answer. Seems to be a property of MysQL (and one which may be changed) rather than PDO. Copy paste that comment as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind values before execute.
This is right way:

```
$STH  = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO Person (firstname, lastname, age) values (?, ?, ?)');
$STH->bindValue(1, 'MyFirstName', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->bindValue(2, 'MyLastName', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->bindValue(3, 28, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$STH->execute();
```